# setState on specific key with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read on some tutorials that we can pass a specific key in parameters of setState in order to update only specific elements. But here is my case :

I use tomchentw's react-google-maps component. I set the options of the map in my App state (then I pass it to the GoogleMap component via props).

**app.jsx**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    //Initial value
    this.state = {
        optionsMap:{
        center: {
            lat: 46.8261444,
            lng: 2.2418121
        },
        zoom: 5
    },
        variables: {}
    }
}
```

**map.jsx**

```
render() {
        return (
            <GoogleMapLoader
                containerElement={ <div {...this.props} style={{ height: '500px'}}></div> }
                googleMapElement={
                     <GoogleMap
                        ref="googleMap"
                        {...this.props.optionsMap} //biding map options with spread
                        onIdle={this._handleIdle.bind(this)}>
                     </GoogleMap>
                }
            />
        );
    }


    _handleIdle(event) {
        this.props.updateVarsOptions(this.props.optionsMap);
    }
```

When I call my updateVarOptions() function (when I moove the map) define in app.jsx, I update the state on the very specific key *variables*.

**app.jsx**

```
_updateVarsOptions(mapOptions) {
        this.setState({
            variables : mapOptions
        });
}
```

So, I update only the *variables* key on the state, but when I do the setState, the map is resettings with the default value (center position and zoom). The state is updating the optionsMap key to. I don't understand why.

Comment: *"The state is updating the optionsMap key to"* That is your assumption based on the behavior of the map? Or did you actually log the value of `this.props.optionsMap`? I'm pretty sure the value is the same, so this could indicate a bug with the `GoogleMap` component itself.

Comment: It's my assumption. The state.optionsMap is not touch. But the DOM is updating, because the map is reset with the state.optionsMap values. Sorry, it's difficult to explain the behavior :(

Comment: The question is, why the DOM of the Google Map is updated while I'm only updating the variables key in setState() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your map is updating with the default values from `optionsMap` is because any call to `setState` will cause the component to re-render (unless there is behavior defined in `shouldComponentUpdate` that says otherwise).  This, in turn, will re-render your Google Maps element and pass the information from the `optionsMap` again, which has not changed since the initial render.

You might want to take a look at the `shouldComponentUpdate` [lifecycle function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate).  This function is involked immediately before rendering, and its return value will tell your component whether or not it should call its `render` function again.  By default, it always returns true.  You can modify this behavior such that your component will not re-render if the `variables` state has changed.

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much! This is my first try with React and ES6, I'm not familiar with any of the possibilities. Anyway, thanks !